# Split string in words before nth occurrence of hashtags in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using the following code in Python to split string into words:

```
keywords=re.sub(r'[][)(!,;]', ' ', str(row[0])).split()
```

imagine the input is :

```
"Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today"
```

I need it to be split in words **only before occurrence of the second** hashtag and **no need to split the rest**, which means the output should be :

```
['Hello','#world','I','am','in']
```

Is there any solution to split the string into keywords in such way in Python?

Comment: Your split is also on white space in the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.find`takes a start position so when you find the first use that index + 1 t start looking for the second then split that substring:

```
s = "Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today"
i =  s.find("#", s.find("#") + 1)
print(s[:i].split())
['Hello', '#world', 'I', 'am', 'in']
```

You can also do the same with index:

```
s = "Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today"
i =  s.index("#", s.index("#") + 1)
print(s[:i].split())
```

The difference being index will raise an error if the substring does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

The split method accepts a character to split by, otherwise it splits on whitespace.

```
string_to_split = "Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today"
# Split on all occurrences of #
temp = string_to_split.split("#")
# Join the first two entries with a '#' and remove any trailing whitespace
temp_two = '#'.join(temp[:2]).strip()
# split on spaces
final = temp_two.split(' ')
```

Run in terminal:

```
>>> string_to_split = "Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today"
>>> temp = string_to_split.split("#")
>>> temp_two = '#'.join(temp[:2]).strip()
>>> final = temp_two.split(' ')
>>> final
['Hello', '#world', 'I', 'am', 'in']
```

Edit: fixed [2:] to [:2] i always get them mixed up

Edit: fixed the extra whitespace issue

Comment: thank you so much I think this answer is more close to what I need, just I'm not sure if it is optimal considering the time complexity in large number of strings as inputs?

Answer (score 2):

interactive python:

```
>>> str="Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today"
>>> hash_indices=[i for i, element in enumerate(str) if element=='#']
>>> hash_indices
[6, 21, 39]
>>> str[0:hash_indices[1]].split()
['Hello', '#world', 'I', 'am', 'in']
>>> str[hash_indices[1]:]
'#London and it is #sunny today'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex and split

```
source = "Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today"
reg_out = re.search('[^#]*#[^#]*#', source)
split_out = reg_out.group().split()
print split_out[:-1]
```

O/P:['Hello', '#world', 'I', 'am', 'in']